# Generalist badge "Top 40 tags"

Tags: discussion, tags, badges

The Generalist badge states that a user needs to provide non-wike answers of 15 total score in 20 of the top 40 tags. I've got two (okay one) question(s) about this.

1. I would say it pretty obviously means 15 net upvotes (number of up - number of down) in *each* tag - is that correct?
2. Does this mean 20 of the user's top 40 tags (as displayed at the bottom of the [user page](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/11762/jim)), or 20 of the sites top 40 tags (as seen on the [tags page's "popular" tab](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags?tab=popular))?

Comment: 15 total score on answers = 1.5 upvotes.

Comment: Score is counted by votes, not by reputation

Comment: Is it? My mistake, then.

Comment: The score of a post is the difference between the number of up-votes, and the number of down-votes.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Thanks, I've edited that in.

Comment: @Jim _Score_ was the correct term; my comment was to make clear that a score of 15 doesn't mean 1.5 votes.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Yes, my question had indicated that, but it simply said "15 upvotes" without including the negative impact of downvotes (I think it's pretty obvious, but it never hurts to be clear and specific)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this [query](http://data.stackexchange.com/english/query/35591/generalist-progression-updated) on Data Explorer. It gives your score for each of the site's current top 40 tags.

I can see that of the current top 40 tags, I have seven with >=15 score, and you have two with >=15 score.

kiamlaluno has 36 but doesn't have the badge. In fact, [no-one](https://english.stackexchange.com/badges/14/generalist) on English.SE has this badge yet. Why not? Well, English.SE isn't ready to award the badge yet -- the top 40 tags each need at least 200 questions. This [query](http://data.stackexchange.com/english/query/11020/is-the-site-ready-for-the-generalist-badge) shows we still have 15/40 tags under the threshold.

Comment: Thanks, now I don't need to ask this.

Answer (score 7):

Basing on the [FAQ entry](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/67399#67399) present on Meta Stack Overflow, the description of the badge is the following one:

> - silver; awarded once
> - Earn a tag score of 15 on one of the top 40 tags
> - Repeat the above step until any 20 of the top 40 tags are covered
> - Only awarded to anyone after each of the 40 top tags has at least 200 questions
> - Source: [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85048/does-the-generalist-badge-require-15-score-total-or-15-score-per-tag/85050#85050), which a dev [said was correct](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/583319#583319).

15 is the score you need for each of the 20 tags; the top 40 tags is the top 40 tags for the site, not the user.